# Kotlin RecyclerView stops creating items after screen is full

Tags: android-recyclerview, dynamic

After the screen fills up with items in my RecyclerView it stops creating more. The data for the items are loaded but the items are never made. In the two images below you can see that in the logs there are more couple more items below the last item that was created in the RecyclerView

[image: RecyclerView scrolled all the way to the bottom to show the last item that was created]

[image: Log of all images that were loaded in for items to be created]

**Here is my code for the RecyclerView:**

```
class FavoritedDrinksFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var favoritedDrinkRecyclerView: RecyclerView
    private var adapter: DrinkAdapter? = DrinkAdapter(emptyList())
    private var callbacks: NavCallbacks? =null

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        callbacks = context as NavCallbacks?
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_favorited_drinks, container, false)
        favoritedDrinkRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.favorited_drink_recycler_view)
        favoritedDrinkRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        favoritedDrinkRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
        setNestedScrollingEnabled(favoritedDrinkRecyclerView, false)
        return view
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)


        var drinks: List<FavoriteDrinkItem> = fetchDrinksFromFile("favoriteDrinks.txt")
        favoritedDrinkRecyclerView.adapter = DrinkAdapter(drinks)
    }

    private fun fetchDrinksFromFile(fileName: String): List<FavoriteDrinkItem> {

        var drinkList = mutableListOf<FavoriteDrinkItem>()

        //File Setup
        val path = context!!.filesDir
        val directory = File(path, "LET")
        directory.mkdirs()
        val inputFile = File(directory, fileName)

        //Reader
        val reader = BufferedReader(FileReader(inputFile))

        //Loop through file and build list
        reader.forEachLine {
            val drinkItem = Gson().fromJson(it, FavoriteDrinkItem::class.java)
            drinkList.add(drinkItem)

        }
        reader.close()
        return drinkList
    }

    inner class DrinkHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view), View.OnClickListener {
        private lateinit var drink: FavoriteDrinkItem

        var drinkNameTextView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.drink_name)
        var drinkImageImageView: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.drink_image)

        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
        }

        fun bind(drink: FavoriteDrinkItem){
            this.drink = drink

            drinkNameTextView.text = this.drink.name.toString()

            getImageFromURL(drink.thumbnail.toString(),drinkImageImageView)
        }

        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            callbacks?.onDrinkSelected(this.drink)
        }
    }

    private inner class DrinkAdapter(var drinks: List<FavoriteDrinkItem>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<DrinkHolder>() {


        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): DrinkHolder {
            val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_favorited_drink, parent, false)
            return DrinkHolder(view)
        }

        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return drinks.size
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DrinkHolder, position: Int) {
            val drink = drinks[position]
            holder.bind(drink)
        }
    }

    private fun getImageFromURL(url: String, imageView: ImageView) {
        Picasso.get().load(url).into(imageView)
    }

}
```

I want the RecyclerView to dynamicaly add more items to itself as I scroll down.